# How to run the other keyword if the test case fail in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

While I'm running one of my test cases in my robot file, I want to send the file if this test case fail. Not just for one condition, it's like keep detecting the errors, if you find it, you send the file and RF will help you stop this test case. So I don't think `Run keyword if` is the best choice. It seems like it just can use only one time.

Also I want to ask that if the test case fail, could it keep executing the same test case? But I still want to know all the errors it has. I know there is `Run Keyword And Ignore Error` but I don't think it can let all the errors show on the screen. It just ignore the fail without printing the error.

Are there the keywords could do these questions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try keyword `Run Keyword And Warn On Failure`. The keyword should not fail, but you should have warning in the log to make it more visible, unlike `Run Keyword And Ignore Error`.

Comment: What you are doing is running multiple tests in a single test and that is the mistake. If you want to do multiple validations whatever the previous result is, then separate those validations into multiple test cases and you will have the results in the end of the execution

Comment: @ClaudioBatista you are correct. I would rather split the testcase as well, however that was not the question, and it is technicaly possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm doing a big test plan. I choose to let this whole plan written in one file and separate with test case is because when I want this file to run the whole cases, which will cost a lot of time, I will leave and do other things. So I don't want to always keep my eyes on it. I hope when I come back I could know all the errors and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Run Keyword and Continue on Failure.
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure

This will run the other keywords in test after the failure occurred. The test report will be showing all failures.